# Rounding decimals to nearest 5th c#

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm currently trying to calculate an exact number from a formula, but am having trouble converting decimal components of a whole number,

For example, if I divide 10 by 3 I'll have 3.3333, My calculation would need to be from 3.2. If I had 6.5, My calculation would need to be off 6.4.

Where I'm struggling is catching the decimal of this moving number, then rounding only the decimal part of that number. Some example of my code is below

```
// This number should be rounded down to the nearest .2
TopCalc = (In - UpperThreshold) * (TopPerc / 100);

// This number should be rounded down to the nearest .2
MidCalc = (UpperThreshold - LowerThreshold) * (MidPerc / 100);

// This number should be rounded down to the nearest .2
LowCalc = LowerThreshold * (LowPerc / 100);

decimal Total = TopCalc + MidCalc + LowCalc;

return Total;
```

So breaking it down further, lets say each 0.2 is a 20Cents/Pence coin, 90 % of a coin is not legal tender, so in a situation of you having to give $/£120.36 and all you have for change is 20 cents/pence pieces, you would only give $/£120.20 as the 16Cents/Pence does not make up a whole coin in this example. Some more examples are below

```
1.235 = 1.2
1.599 = 1.4
1.611 = 1.6
1.799999999999 = 1.6
1.85 = 1.8
```

*Always rounding down to the nearest literal 0.2 never rounding up.*

Comment: what do you mean by "the nearest `.2`"? In your first example (`3.3333 == 3.2`), it sounds like you mean the literal `.2`, but in your second example (`6.5 == 6.4`) it seems like you mean the nearest even number. But then that would make your first example not accurate, since the nearest even number is `.4`

Comment: I see what your saying, I would say rounding down to the nearest literal .2. So basically 1.9 is 0, 3.9 is 2, no rounding up

Comment: Sorry, but that is even more confusing. Now your examples are ignoring the decimal altogether and just rounding down to the nearest, whole, even number. Please update your question with precisely what you want, and some extreme examples that clarify it.

Comment: Hi Rufus, Sorry it was late my side and I've just realised the above is not the clearest example, I've clarified a bit further and tried to sum up a touch clearer what I'm looking to achieve

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like

```
static decimal NthRound(decimal d, decimal nth)
{
    var intPart = decimal.Truncate(d);
    var fifth = decimal.Truncate(nth * (d - intPart)) / nth;
    return intPart + fifth ;           
}
```

and then

```
Console.WriteLine( NthRound(10M/2M, 5M));
Console.WriteLine( NthRound(10M/3M, 5M));
Console.WriteLine( NthRound(13M/2M, 5M));
```

which gets

[image]

which rounds down to the nearest 5th in this case

Answer (score 1):

Are your decimals always positive, or can they be negative?

I managed to get this to work, but it's not very elegant. There may be a better solution:

```
    decimal d = 2.235M;
    int i;

    d = Math.Round(d, 1);
    i = (int) (d*10);
    i = i >> 1;
    i = i << 1;
    d = (decimal) i/10;
```

Comment: The decimals will always be positive, I'm just installing an SDK, but will feedback the results, its a tricky one to say the least